# Como deixar um Dialog com as pontas arredondadas (bordas) via código sem usar xml?

Tags: android

Para layouts, Buttons e EditTexts eu uso a classe `ShapeDrawable` mais especificamente o `RoundRectShape` e funciona perfeitamente, porém para Dialogs e ListViews isso não funciona. Alguém sabe o que usar para deixar Dialogs e ListViews com bordas ou mais especificamente cantos arredondados? Agradeço desde já. Se é que é possível fazer isso.

Comment: Sem usar nada de xml ? Essa resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501488/android-alertdialog-with-rounded-corners

Utiliza o xml para definir o layout do dialog acho que resolve seu problema

Comment: Você tem algum tipo de restrição que te impede de utilizar xml?

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog =  super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);   
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    return dialog;
}
```